# How to fix "ImportError at / cannot import name "bar" " for the HelloWorldApp example?

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie in Django. last week, I did all the steps for running the HelloWorld example by this tutorial: http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/visual-studio-code-with-python-django/
which worked perfectly. However, I was trying to run it today, and it is not working. when i run: "python manage.py runserver", I got the message of "0 error found", but in the browser I have the following error:

Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: cannot import name bar

[error message on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aA4N.png)

can anyone please help me? need to mention that I tried all posted answer into the similar question, but the problem is still there!! Thanks
[The structure of project's folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZGtD.png)

```
"views.py":
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render

"urls.py":
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from HelloWorldApp.views import bar

  urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'HelloWorldApp/$', bar),
  ]
```

Comment: Can you screenshot the full browser error please?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aA4N.png      Here you are Matthew! Thank you

Comment: Ok, can you now add the code (not an image, but pasted into the question) for your HelloWorldApp.views? It would be the views.py file. Your urls.py would be helpful as well.

Comment: Can you show the contents of folder HelloWorldApp, this should contain a python file called views.py and in it a function bar.

Comment: Thanks @bruno. The folder contains: _init_.py, admin.py, apps.py, models.py and indeed views.py with the "bar" function inside. As I mentioned in my first post, I was able to see the output on the browser on a day that I created it, but today I got the error!!!                                                                                                   In the view.py, on the line "from django.shortcuts import render", a problem-box appears as: "Unable to import 'django.shortcuts' pylint(import-error)"............If it is related to pylint, I have it installed in my system.

Comment: That is strange indeed. Something must have been done in the past three days as code not just stop working! What is this "views.py"? As far as I can tell it is not necessary... Can you show the folder structure of the project?

Comment: @bruno, please find the structure here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZGtD.png   .....It is strange, I have no clue what I  have done that has affected on this. I made a virtualenv for the project. Could be that related?! sorry for maybe stupid questions!

Comment: Yes structure looks ok. I suggest you remove all *.pyc files so it 'recompiles' byte-code again and see what happens. I take it you (or vs  rather) activates the virtual environment.

Comment: I deleted all *.pyc files and did the steps again, still got the same error!!

Comment: Unless I have access to your code I am afraid I can not help further. Is your code in Github or another repository? Otherwise with virtual environment activated start from scratch and see if you can get it working again. So far not much code is involved.

Comment: since I am newer in Django, I did not push it on my repository, simply just followed the instructions in (http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/visual-studio-code-with-python-django/) to get into Django to create a webapp. As you suggested, I am going to do all from scratch. Hopefully, meanwhile I will figure it out the cause of the error, because it is bugging me now:) Thanks a lot @Bruno

Comment: Good luck. Let me know if you succeeded and what the bug was in the end.

Comment: Hi Bruno, at the end, Idid all from scratch again by following the instruction in the provided tutorial above and it worked! However, unfortunately, I could not figure it out what the problem was:( Again, thank you so much for your time and guide.

Comment: Probably something with the virtual environment. Anyway good to hear you are on track again.